# Onepagecheckout -> Programmatically fill out shipping form with billing address (guest)

Tags: onepage-checkout, shipping-address, billing-address

**Onepagecheckout:** If I jump back to shipping address (i.e. from step shipping method or payment method) then  I do see an empty shipping address form.

Since I "force" the customers to use billing address as shipping address I want to pre populate the shipping fields with billing address 
**(automatically fill out shipping address for guests by using billing address)**.

The concerning template is `frontend/default/mytheme/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml.`

All shipping fields would get filled out automatically if a customer is logged in because all fields have values like

```
value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getCity()) ?>
```

**So actually my goal is to overwrite $this->getAddress()** with the data from billing address. But I can't get it to work!

What I got so far in

`frontend/default/mytheme/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml`

```
// Load billing address
$checkout = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$bilAddress = $checkout->getBillingAddress();

// Load customer model
$customAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address');
$customAddress->setData($bilAddress);

// Now I want to set billing address as shipping address. But none of these 3 approaches work.
$checkout->setShippingAddress(Mage::getSingleton('sales/quote_address')->importCustomerAddress($customAddress));
$this->setShippingAddress(Mage::getSingleton('sales/quote_address')->importCustomerAddress($customAddress));
$checkout->getShippingAddress()->setSameAsBilling(true);
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I ran out of ideas.
Thank you very much for any help! I appreciate it!

Comment: Your address exist in quote, did you try to make smth like $quote->getBillingAddress()->get....() ?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Yes, actually I load the quote object in $checkout. But it doesn't work:( Also tried $checkout->setAddress($bilAddress);
$checkout->getAddress()->setData($bilAddress);
$this->setAddress($bilAddress);

Comment: Nope, I meaned another thing. I put into value default value from billing address. At this moment quote don't have shipping address!!! Once you jump to shipping information your address will be saved

Comment: Thanks zhartaunik. It doesn't solve my initial question but its a nice work around! Probably I will have to go with this. Thanks again!